# Saving which radio button has been checked

Tags: html, css, checkbox, blazor

I have a list of three radio buttons and I'm trying to figure out how I can display which one has been clicked and saved. These radio buttons are in my Blazor project and the UpdateFilter method on the on click just saves the string to the database. How can I make the one that is clicked and saved show as checked when the page is loaded?

```
        <label class="GroupTitle">Filters:</label><br/>
        <input type="radio" name="number" id="all" @oninput="@(() => UpdateFilter("all"))" /> 
        <label for="">Clear all files</label><br />  
        <input type="radio" name="number" id="number" @oninput="@(() => UpdateFilter("number"))" />
        <label for="">Based on number of files</label><br />    
        <input type="radio" name="number" id="date" @oninput="@(() => UpdateFilter("date"))" />    
        <label for="date">Based on date of files</label><br />
```

Comment: You can use the "checked" attribute for the radio input. Here is the documentation on working with radio buttons in blazor: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-and-input-components?view=aspnetcore-3.1#radio-buttons

Comment: @SarahCox Would this be able to read from the database to know which one should be checked when the page is refreshed / loaded?

Comment: You would need to set it when the page loads using the OnInitialized function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-6.0. To get the info for a specific record you will need to pass in a parameter to the page to identify the record: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/parameters-in-blazor-server-deep-dive/

Comment: @SarahCox Okay I have it reading from the database now, but it only selects one from the last component. Do you know how I could make all the components do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should really be using the `<InputRadioGroup>` component. Here is a very contrived example:

```
<EditForm Model="this.model">
    <InputRadioGroup @bind-Value="this.model.Filter">
        @foreach (var filterOption in this.FilterOptions)
        {
            <label><InputRadio Value="@filterOption.Key" />&nbsp;@filterOption.Value</label>
            <br />
        }
    </InputRadioGroup>
</EditForm>

@code{
    private Model model = new Model();
    private Dictionary<string, string> FilterOptions = new
    {
        { "all", "Clear all files" },
        { "number", "Based on number of files" },
        { "date", "Based on date of files" },
    }

    public class Model
    {
        public string Filter { get; set; }
    }
}
```